# Toggle div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

// when the document has finished loading, get the data
$(document).ready(GetData());

function GetData() {

    $.ajax({
        beforSend: function () {
            $('#loadingDiv').css('display', 'block')
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loadingDiv').css('display', 'none')
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Integrationsonify/Data.aspx",
        data: dataObject,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var header = $("#accordion");

            $.each(data, function () {

                header.append("<a href='javascript:toggleDiv();'>" + this.Name + " </a>", "<div id='myContent' style='display:none'>" + "<ul>", "<li>" + this.Id + "</li>", "<li>" + this.SName + "</li>", "</ul>" + "</div");

            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("There was an error while rendering the page. Please contact the Admin for details");
        }

    });

   }
   function toggleDiv() {

                  $("#myContent").toggle();

   }

</script>
<div id="loadingDiv" style="display: block;">
    hi
</div>
<div id="accordion">

</div>
```

I am unable to toggle the myContent div..Is it because its created in ajax call?? The div is displayed but if I do a view source for the page I cannot see any data inside my accordion div..but on ui side in the browser I can atleast see the data..Thanks I am very sorry, I know its a very basic question but I need to find my way out of this very soon now so please guide me...

Comment: View source only displays what the page looks like before any DOM manipulation.  You need to use Firebug or something similar to that to see what it looks like at the current stage

Comment: you are also missing a > at the end, you wrote `</div"` instead than `</div>"`

Comment: Could you maybe use jsfiddle.net? Give us a demo?

Comment: use the web developer tools for your browser instead the view source option. The web developer tools give you a view to the rendered source.

Comment: <div id="accordion">
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv();">Life Guard Training</a>
<div id="myContent" style="display:none">
<ul></ul>
</div>
<li>908</li>
<li>Training</li>
</div>

Comment: this is from the firebug li is getting appended after div end

Comment: @Dom when I click on the anchor tag the style="display:none" gets appended to the div

Answer (score 2):

Use `beforeSend` instead of `beforSend`. And you should use `hide()` and `show()` to hide/show your div, it's clearer.

**EDIT :**

I don't know what data you are expecting, and as such I can't really help you, but try debugging it this way :

- if you are in chrome, right-click anywhere on your page and click on "inspect this element" (or smthg like that)
- if you are in firefox, download firebug extension
- if you are in IE, download one of the previous browsers

You will find some ways of debugging js with this tools on the internet, and it will be really helpful if you do a lot of js.

Just an advice, try to insert HTML this way when you use jQuery, it's far more readable, and you can debug it :

```
header.append(
    $('<a/>').click(function() {
        toggleDiv();
        return false;
    }),
    $('<div id="myContent"/>').hide().append(
        $('<ul/>').append(
            $('<li/>').text(this.Id),
            $('<li/>').text(this.SName)
        )
    )
);
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Sorry, I didn't really think it through, it should be :

```
$('<a/>').click(function() {
    toggleDiv($(this));
    return false;
})
```

And in your toggleDiv function :

```
function toggleDiv ($elem) {
    $elem.next().toggle();
}
```

I think this will work

**EDIT 3 :**

Of course you should put `$('<div class="myContent"/>')` because HTML specifications forbid multiple elements with the same id. then, your selector becomes `$('.myContent')` and returns multiple elements

Answer (score 0):

I just replaces (,) with (+) and it started working ..weird!!!

Comment: this just work for the single data filed ..if I get more then one data filed s in the .each function the there are repetition of id's and so only the first data toggles correctly after that the remaining anchor tags don't toggle...again stuck...   @Arthur Jaouen

Comment: function toggleDiv(element) {
           var x = element.next();
           x.toggle();